# if <meta> is deprecated for auto refreshing, what should i use?

Tags: html

I've been using `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">` for a little while to auto update my pages, and then I found that clicking refresh before the 5 seconds is up causes the auto update not to work, at least in IE8.

So I decided to research the `<meta>` tag and found, according to wikipedia: " Auto refreshing via a META element has been deprecated for more than ten years [5] and recognized as problematic before that ".

So, what SHOULD I be using to auto update my pages?  (I am guessing it will be a javy scripty kinda thingy.)

Thanks bunches in advance!!!!

Comment: How are you using it to refresh?  If you are constantly refreshing every 5 seconds you are probably making a lot of people very upset. Look into AJAX to update your content instead.

Comment: Hi Evan. No complaints from angry users yet, but it's not a mass-consumption application, rather a small special purpose app. A Java thread is doing some work on the Tomcat server side and the auto-refresh page calls a Struts action to see if the thread is done and then the action sends them to a results page if it's done. I should probably use AJAX as you suggest, but actually I'm a Java developer with modest HTML and Javascript abilities, and AJAX is still just over the horizon for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you can do it easily with javascript.

Something like that:

```
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
```

I don't know what you really want to do, but refreshing the entire page might be overkill.

Consider using JQuery/AJAX to refresh only a part of your page.

Comment: Thanks! Um, I tried it and it works, except for the fact that IE8 throws up a message box saying "To display the web page again the browser needs to resubmit the data you just sent...", which is I think it's standard behaviour when clicking "Refresh". Is there an argument to setTimeout() to tell IE not to do that? If not, how much work would it be to switch to an AJAX solution?  (BTW I gave your post the 'accepted answer' tick because you gave a javascript sample AND said 'try ajax'.)

Comment: Thanks :-)  about the "To display the web page again the browser needs to resubmit the data you just sent..." this is because you refresh a page that post data and the result of your post is not redirected to a display page.  Make sure you use HTTP GET instead of HTTP POST to avoid the problem.  For the AJAX solution, if you use JQuery, its very simple.  Just google Ajax Jquery example and voila.... you should find a lot of example.  good luck

Answer (score 5):

use

```
<script>
 setTimeout("window.location.reload(true);",5000);
</script>
```

or

```
<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="window.location.reload()">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
function timedRefresh() {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",5000);
}
```

This will put a timeout on your page to trigger a refresh every 5 seconds.

Comment: it is a bad practice to pass string instead function to setTimeout

Comment: I've heard that, however I do it all the time and have never had any issues, especially for a simple task such as this.

Comment: Bad practice doesn't mean that it doesn't work. It means there are subtle gotchas that can cause it to work differently than you would expect, which you may not notice until the right combination of factors triggers it.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone has gone the javascript "alternative", but I would like to also stand by and mention that if you find yourself needing to refresh the whole page, it may be time to decide if [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) is worth it for your site.

Depending on the content(s) being refreshed, the "new standard" is to use AJAX behind the scenes to poll/refresh content, and keeps browsing history in tact.

Comment: Thanks Brad.  Question:  To implement an AJAX version of an auto-refresh, do I need to read a 350 page book (because I do actually have one).  Or can I copy/paste-inherit something that does what I need? As I mentioned in another comment, I'm only a Java developer with modest HTML and Javascript ability and I haven't ventured into AJAX yet.

Comment: @John: Do you have a sample of the page that you're trying to refresh? Also, what kind of information is susceptible to change? (Is it tables of information, complete content shift, paragraphs, etc?)

Comment: The page is actually fully static, with only an animated gif and a message saying "Please wait...", and the `<meta>` tag.  It keeps refreshing itself every 5 seconds (using the `<meta>` tag) going to an http URL that corresponds to a Java Struts action, that internally checks the progress of a background thread.  If that separate thread is done, it gets result information from an object (a Java bean) stored in the user's session (that was put there by the separate thread).  It then forwards to ANOTHER page that displays the result information that was stored in the Java bean.

Comment: @John: So can you create a separate page that just returns the running status of the worker? Then you can use AJAX and poll that page repeatedly looking for change. Once change is acknowledged, you can forward them on to the landing page.

Answer (score -3):

```
<body onLoad="setTimeout('window.location = window.location;',5000);">
```

Comment: So... painful... Using onload directly, not spelling it right, passing a STRING to setTimeout, not using location.reload...