# A way to redirect in PHP without header(Location: somefile.php) and without ob_start()?

Tags: php, javascript, html, redirect, header

Is there any way to do a PHP redirect without utilization of the `header()` or `ob_start()` functions?

I am currently using a bit of JS, injected in the PHP script, to get the job done (and yes, it's working):

```
?> <script type="text/javascript">location.assign('index.php');</script> <?php
```

JS has quite a simple function `location.assign()` that doesn't need headers to redirect the user; does PHP have such a function?

Is there no other way?

Comment: Would you mind telling us the reason you don't want to use header()?

Comment: I have HTML output to the browser before the line that contains the redirect in question

Comment: Not in php. Why can't you redo the logic so it checks conditions first before outputting to browser? Or use ob_start. Why cant you just use the javascript function?

Comment: I know I could but to to me it is strange that PHP wouldn't have such a function built in..? It seems there may be no such function

Comment: header() IS the built in function, it just takes a few steps on your part to ensure it works properly.

Comment: Because, it isn't PHP(server) that controls the page redirect, it is the browser (client)

Comment: Javascript works dynamically with the DOM, PHP outputs HTML. I don't think that it'd be an issue with PHP, but how browsers lack a redirect functionality besides `header`, `meta` tags, javascript and the likes.

Comment: @Kris: ah. That is the fundamental answer I was looking for. at Sam: header() is *A* built in function but does not satisfy what I was referring to. I suppose there's no way around it. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there no other way?

A meta-redirect in `<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=NEW_PAGE_URL" />
```

Comment: It needs to be written into the PHP logic though, because I don't want the page to simply redirect by default, you see?

Comment: `if ({PHP LOGIC}) echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=NEW_PAGE_URL" />';` in the `head`. But then you could also apply that logic to the `location` header before outputting HTML..

Comment: @FabrícioMatté This is helpful, and I could do it this way, although it's not entirely what I was looking for.

Comment: Yeah man, I can't think of an usercase where you'd need this, I'd go for the `location` header with the logic tested before outputting HTML personally, it might require rewriting some of the logic though.. Well, as long as it works it's fine. One thing though that I'd note on shhac's answer, `http-equiv="refresh"` is [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6751091/1331430). [W3C source](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WD-WAI-PAGEAUTH-19990226/wai-pageauth-tech.html#tech-no-single-refresh)

Comment: The only advantage of it is that it doesn't require JavaScript to be enabled. If I wanted to redirect, my order of preference would be header > script > meta.

Comment: why header > script >meta? header > meta > script seems less prone to fail

Comment: @RidIculous Meta refresh tags are depreciated and less powerful in what you can do with them (e.g. what happens if you want to carry forward a GET or want to POST stuff)?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I wasn't aware that they are being depreciated. Does PHP header:location also forward $_POST data? I didn't know that.